# Can an SVN repository be cloned as a Git bare repository with a simple command?

Tags: git, git-svn

I need to clone an [SVN repository](https://sourceforge.net/p/syntaxhighlight/code/HEAD/tree/) as a bare Git repo.

At the moment, I accomplished this by:

1. Cloning the SVN repo with [`git-svn`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-svn):

   ```
   $ git svn clone http://svn.code.sf.net/p/syntaxhighlight/code/
   ```
2. Moving the `.git` directory to the wanted place:

   ```
   $ mv code/.git /srv/git/syntaxhighlight
   ```

But I don't find this really handy and I cannot see any reference to `bare` when I `man git svn`. Besides, if the SVN repo has been updated, I can run `git svn fetch`, but I get errors when I try to rebase.

Can any option do the trick?

Ideally, I would like an option similar to [`git clone --mirror`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone#_options).

Running Git 2.1.4

Answer (score 2):

After moving the `.git` directory to the wanted place you missed doing the following:

```
$ rm -rf code    # you might want to get rid of the check-out
$ cd /srv/git/syntaxhighlight
$ git config --bool core.bare true
```

I found the following Stackoverflow question [How to convert a normal Git repository to a bare one?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2199897/how-to-convert-a-normal-git-repository-to-a-bare-one) providing the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2200662) to your problem.

To your question about `git svn rebase`: I can't think of using `git rebase` on a bare repository. I only use it on a normal git repository. So I think the same applies for `git svn rebase`.

`git svn fetch` works in a normal or bare repository because it works without a checkout directory.